# What is the function to create a project for BIM 360?

Tags: c#, .net, api, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to create a project for BIM 360 using C#. So far I have been able to get it to work on POSTMAN but I want to perform the same function on C#. Is there a method I can use that to create a project using the following:

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects`

I have tried to use ProjectsApi and HubsApi but they don't seem to have the correct parameters.

Comment: If you can get it to work with Postman then you already have the API method.

Comment: Thanks, I found the code related to what I input into Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the .NET package for Forge does not yet include BIM 360 specific endpoints... so you'll need to use [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/) (or similar packages), [like this sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/3c724b92de3b25cf9a094dd2b58f4e56351a87a2/data.management-csharp-sample/Controllers/BIM360Controller.cs#L78).